# Simple Java alert for debugging purposes

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug/trace how some Java code is executed (or if it even is). I would like a simple way to do an alert just so I can tell how the code is being executed. Something like:

```
alert ("do we get here");
```

in javascript, or:

```
echo ("do we get here");
```

in php.

I have googled it but alot of the methods seem fairly complicated and an excessive amount of code. I am new to java, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: as in: `System.out.println("I'm here");` ?

Comment: System.out.println(<String>); will print to the cout. You can also use a variety of logging systems which give you a finer grained control over your debugging statements. See log4j and slf4j.

Comment: I would suggest you look into using a Java Debugger

Answer (score 1):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Message");
```

The null part can actually be switched by a proper parent component, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.out.println("Here we are");
```

but if you want to know how we got there you can use

```
new Throwable("Here we are").printStackTrace(System.out);
```

and it will print the call stacka s well.

Answer (score 0):

`Sytem.out.println("do we get here");`

Comment: Assuming you are using an IDE like Netbeans, IntelliJ Idea or Eclipse, you might prefer to set breakpoints and running the app in debug mode. You do not even have to type anything, then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do text output to the screen, you could just use `System.out.println("Point 1");`. If you are after a more visual thing (which I am assuming you are), you could take a look at the `JOptionPane` class, with more information available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

A more traditional (an most likely preferred) way of doing something like what you are after would be use Loggin. [`SLF4J`](http://www.slf4j.org/) is a relatively popular way of doing logging in a Java application.